# jQuery mousemove fires on its own

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to take a video player full screen, and I want the controls to show on `mousemove`. Since there is no `mousestop` I just started a timer and if it ever completes, it will hide the tools.

*the problem* – due to the nature of the callbacks I suspect, the effect keeps switching back and forth between show and hide. The class `mouseMoving` is used in css to add `display: block !important` and when it is removed, `theControls` returns to it's original css which is `display: none !important`

```
 $('#theDiv').mousemove(

        function()
        {
          //When the mouse is moving, add the class which adds display: block !important
          $('#theControls').addClass('mouseMoving');

          // Clear the timer each time the mouse moves, so that if the mouse doesnt move for a full 2 seconds,
          // hide the controls by removing the afforementioned class.

          clearTimeout(timer);

          var timer = setTimeout(

            function() 
            {
              $('#theControls').removeClass('mouseMoving');
            },

          2000);
        }
      );
```

In fact, if you go full screen and move the mouse, the controls will appear, then hide, and then the dev tools will show that the class `mouseMoving` is constantly being appended and removed, *even though I am no longer moving the mouse*. This will continue indefinitely, or until the mouse is moved again, but then the cycle repeats.

Comment: why do you call `clearTimer`  on `timer` before it is defined? Shouldn't you want to define `timer` outside of the closure so you can do that?

Comment: And also, did you mean `clearTimer` or `clearTimeout`? Because `clearTimer` does not exist unless you defined it.

Comment: @ahitt6345 I meant `clearTimeout` sorry, changed it above.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/Lfzt5u9j/37/

Basically, take the `!important` property  off of your `display:none !important;` part in the css and put it on the `display:block` in `.mouseMoving`. The reason you have to do this is because whatever is in the ID part of your css overrides the CLASS part of your css. If you don't get it, mess around with my fiddle or ask questions :D

Then, make your Js look like my fiddle.

```
var timer;
$('#theDiv').mousemove(function() {
    //When the mouse is moving, add the class which adds display: block !important
    //console.log($('.mouseMoving'));
    $('#theControls').addClass('mouseMoving');

    // Clear the timer each time the mouse moves, so that if the mouse doesnt move for a full 2 seconds,
    // hide the controls by removing the afforementioned class.
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('#theControls').removeClass('mouseMoving');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Actually, in order to override `!important` all you have to do in your case is make the class selector more specific.

like if your class for `mouseMoving` is

```
.mouseMoving {
    display:block !important;
}
```

change it to:

```
div#theControls.mouseMoving {
    display:block !important;
}
```

Comment: I can't remove the `!important` from it because otherwise the controls will never hide. There is something else in the code that puts an inline style on the tools that is `display: block` that is why I must use `!important` to override that. I am working out of an already established code base so that's why it is difficult.

Comment: It also doesnt work when you use `$('.mouseMoving').removeClass();` instaed of how it originally was. It never reappears after hiding the first time.

Comment: Really? when you do `removeClass` without parameters, it just removes all the classes associated with the element.